# C++ conditional link with preprocessor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hyperlink, preprocessor

I have a MSVC C++ project, I am conditionally compiling parts of the source code by passing specifing Preprocessor Defintions in the C++/Preprocessor section of the Project Properties.

What I would also like to do is conditionally link with libraries based on the preprocessor definitions, how do I achieve this?

For example in my project if CLSOPENLDV is defined I want to exclude:

nodetalk32_vcpp.obj

and include:

ldv32.lib

And when it isn't defined I want to do the opposite.

Comment: Read about [`#pragma comment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx).

Comment: You can decide which libraries to include or link using statement `ifdef` (in header file) or `ifeq` (in Makefile) :-)

Comment: @Paradowski A MSVC C++ Project is unlikely to be driven by a makefile...

Comment: @Paradowski, including headers is not the same as excluding libraries from the build,

Comment: @Some programmer dude, a pragma will influence what happens in the source, but the libraries will still be included in the build process....I want it to conditionally include or exclude libraries from the build.

Comment: Since you are defining those macros in Project Properties it would make sense to specify libraries to be linked in Project Properties as well.

Comment: @VTT, the question is how?

Comment: @SPlatten not quite: `#pragma comment( lib, "mylib" )`  influences also the linker. This pragma is Microsoft specificc

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I'll edit my question to include more information.

Comment: Go to Linker -> Input section and add libraries to Additional dependencies

Comment: @VTT, I see that and I realise I can edit this, but is it possible to generate this using a preprocessor?

Comment: @SPlatten The first question is: Why do you want to do that? Even if the libraries are passed to the linker, the linker should find that no symbols of the library are needed and ignore them.

Comment: @Rene, on the development system I am working on I have both libraries installed, so building isn't a problem, however the team is larger and not everyone has the libraries installed and these aren't required, so to build one variant without linker errors I need to build without the library.

Comment: No, those settings can not be changed with preprocessor (though you can use alternative approach involving `#pragma comment( lib ...` to supply list of libraries to be linked). Setting up Properties initially requires about the same amount of work as using `#pragma comment` however it should be the preferred way of setting up build configuration because Properties can be later exported and easily reused in other projects.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you, now resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need this:

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO
#pragma comment( lib, "ldv32" )
#endif
```

This is Microsoft specific, it probably won't work with gcc, clang or other compilers.

For excluding `nodetalk32_vcpp.obj` the only thing you can do that comes into my mind is:

```
#ifndef SOME_MACRO
  // content of nodetalk32_vcpp.cpp
#endif
```

Comment: Sorted, ".lib" not required in pragma, unfortunately I don't have the source code for nodetalk32_vcpp

Comment: Using VS2017, .lib at the end is required.